# How to read second row column value in first row column

Tags: java, mysql, displaytag

I am using display tag to display table it is working fine but i have new requirement that "i need to display second row column value in first row column and third row value in second row column....i.e
for me data coming like this in table format:

```
 Sr No.      From Date                   To Date        Duration(hh:mm:ss)  
    1    01-Nov-2013 12:17:00 PM                                2d 20:23:22       
    2    04-Nov-2013 09:40:35 AM                        01:20:37       
    3            04-Nov-2013 11:27:21 AM                    05:23:35
```

But i need table data will be like below:

```
Sr No.      From Date                    To Date        Duration(hh:mm:ss)  
    1   01-Nov-2013 12:17:00 PM   04-Nov-2013 09:40:35 AM           2d 20:23:22       
    2  04-Nov-2013 09:40:35 AM  04-Nov-2013 11:27:21 AM          01:20:37      
    3  04-Nov-2013 11:27:21 AM         4th row 2nd column         05:23:35
```

can any help me how to do this 
In detail java code which i have written will be this
StoppageDBReport.jsp:

```
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c"%>
<%@ taglib prefix="fmt" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/fmt" %>
<%@ taglib uri="http://displaytag.sf.net" prefix="display" %>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/displaytag.css" type="text/css">  
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/screen.css" type="text/css">  
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/site.css" type="text/css">  
<link href="css/sty.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="css/tabborder.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
</head>
<body>


<jsp:include page="Header.jsp" />
    <c:choose>
    <c:when test="${not empty spdetails}">       
            <table id="display_table">
            <tr ><td><b>Stoppage Details</b></td></tr>
            <tr ><td><b><%=request.getParameter("vehicleId") %></b></td></tr>
            <tr><td>From &nbsp;<%=session.getAttribute("fromdate") %>&nbsp;to&nbsp;<%=session.getAttribute("startdate") %></td></tr>

            </table>
            <display:table id="deviceDetailsID" name="sessionScope.spdetailsid" pagesize="10" export="true" sort="list">

   <display:setProperty name="basic.empty.showtable" value="true" />
    <display:setProperty name="paging.banner.group_size" value="10" />
    <display:setProperty name="paging.banner.item_name" value="Record" />
    <display:setProperty name="paging.banner.item_names" value="Records" />

   <display:column property="serialID" title="Sl No" style="width: 3%"/>
    <display:column property="deviceID" title="Device ID"  style="width: 1%"/>
    <display:column property="timestamp" title="From Date"  format="{0,date,dd-MM-yyyy}"/>
    <display:column property="timestamp" title="ToDate" />
    <display:column property="statuscode" title="Status Code"/>
    <display:column property="address" title="Address" />
</display:table> 
</c:when>

<c:otherwise>
<jsp:include page="Pages/Stoppagebody.jsp"/>
<div id="MenuLineDiv" style="width:100%; height: 2px; font-size: 2px; background-color: #FFCD44; position: relative; top: 0px;"></div>
<table width="100%" border="1" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" bordercolor="#FFFFFF">
    <tr class="topheader">
        <td colspan="6" style="color:white;text-align:center;">Stoppage report for <%=request.getParameter("vehicleId") %> from <%=session.getAttribute("fromdate") %> to <%=session.getAttribute("startdate") %> </td>
    </tr>


    <tr class="secondhedr">
        <td colspan="6" style="color:white;text-align:center;">No data found</td>
    </tr>

</table>
  </c:otherwise>
</c:choose>              
    <jsp:include page="Footer.jsp"/>    


</body>
</html>
```

Dao object:

```
public List<StoppageDetails> getSpDetails(String accountID,String deviceID,String Timestamp1,String Timestamp2) {
        Connection con=null;
        List<StoppageDetails> spdetails = new ArrayList<StoppageDetails>();
        try{


            con= DBConnectionFactory.getDBConnection();

            String sql="SELECT accountID,deviceID,TIMESTAMP,address FROM eventdata WHERE (TIMESTAMP BETWEEN '"+Timestamp1+"' AND '"+Timestamp2+"') AND accountID='"+accountID+"' AND deviceID='"+deviceID+"'and speedKPH=0.0";
            Statement st=con.createStatement();
            ResultSet rs=st.executeQuery(sql);
            int count=0;
            System.out.println("::::"+rs.next());
            while (rs.next()){
                StoppageDetails ud=new StoppageDetails();
                ud.setSerialID(count);
                ud.setAccountID(rs.getString(1));
                ud.setDeviceID(rs.getString(2));
                String stringtimestamp=rs.getString(3);
                 long l=Long.parseLong(stringtimestamp);
                 long longtimestamp = l * 1000L;
                 String datestring= new java.text.SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss").format(new java.util.Date(longtimestamp));
                    ud.setTimestamp(datestring);
                    String address=rs.getString(4);
                String address1[]=address.split(" \\d");
                ud.setAddress(address1[0]);
                spdetails.add(ud);
                count++;
              } 

            }catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();

            }
        System.out.println(spdetails);
            return spdetails;


        }
```

controller code:

```
protected void service(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {

        try{
            response.setContentType("text/html");

            HttpSession session=request.getSession(true);

            String accountID=(String)session.getAttribute("sessionId");
            String deviceID=request.getParameter("vehicleId");
            String fromdate=request.getParameter("AnotherDate");
            String todate=request.getParameter("ADate");

            session.setAttribute("vid",deviceID);
            session.setAttribute("fromdate",fromdate);
            session.setAttribute("startdate",todate);
            SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss"); 
            Date startD = (Date) sdf.parse(fromdate);
            Date endD = (Date) sdf.parse(todate);

            Calendar cal1 = Calendar.getInstance();
            Calendar cal2 = Calendar.getInstance();
            cal1.setTime(startD);
            cal2.setTime(endD);

             long timestamp1,timestamp2;
             timestamp1=cal1.getTimeInMillis()/1000;
             timestamp2=cal2.getTimeInMillis()/1000;
            String Timestamp1 = Long.toString(timestamp1);
            String Timestamp2 = Long.toString(timestamp2);



            UserDAO rdao=new UserDAO();
            List<StoppageDetails> spdetails=rdao.getSpDetails(accountID, deviceID, Timestamp1, Timestamp2);

                             session.setAttribute("spdetailsid", spdetails);
                                 RequestDispatcher rd=request.getRequestDispatcher("StoppageDBReport.jsp");
                                    rd.include(request,response);
                            return;

        }catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO: handle exception
        }


    }

}
```

Vo objects:

```
package com.preva.vo;

public class StoppageDetails {

    private String accountID, deviceID,timestamp,address;
    private int serialID;
    public String getTimestamp() {
        return timestamp;
    }

    public void setTimestamp(String timestamp) {
        this.timestamp = timestamp;
    }

    public int getSerialID() {
        return serialID;
    }

    public void setSerialID(int serialID) {
        this.serialID = serialID;
    }

    public String getAccountID() {
        return accountID;
    }

    public void setAccountID(String accountID) {
        this.accountID = accountID;
    }

    public String getDeviceID() {
        return deviceID;
    }

    public void setDeviceID(String deviceID) {
        this.deviceID = deviceID;
    }
    public String getAddress() {
        return address;
    }

    public void setAddress(String address) {
        this.address = address;
    }



}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's possible to do that in mysql with a self join but easiest solution is to just read that value from the next element in a list inside java.

This is from your controller

```
List<StoppageDetails> spdetails=rdao.getSpDetails(accountID, deviceID, Timestamp1, Timestamp2);
for (int i = 0; i < spdetails.size() - 1; i++) {
    StoppageDetails current = spdetails.get(i);
    StoppageDetails next = spdetails.get(i+1);
    current.setTimestamp2(next.getTimestamp());
}
```

Comment: Thanks for responding Andreas can u explain how to do in mysql since i need difference between timestamps also

Answer (score 0):

You can use a query like this -

```
SELECT t1.sr_no, t1.From_Date, t2.From_Date AS To_Date, Duration FROM table1 t1
  LEFT JOIN (SELECT * FROM table1 ORDER BY sr_no) t2
    ON t1.sr_no < t2.sr_no
GROUP BY
  t1.sr_no
```

In this example rows are sorted by **Sr No.** field.